# How do you concatenate strings in a Puppet .pp file?

Tags: string-concatenation, puppet

Here is my naive approach:

```
# puppet/init.pp
$x = 'hello ' + 
     'goodbye'
```

This does not work. How *does* one concatenate strings in Puppet?

Comment: I did not ask exactly the right question. What I should have asked is, is there a string concatenation operator in the Puppet DSL? It appears there is currently no such thing: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/15330

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Keyword variable interpolation:

```
$value = "${one}${two}"
```

Source: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.3/reference/lang_variables.html#interpolation

Note that although it might work without the curly braces, you should always use them.

Comment: Also not that this will only work in a variable assignment as demonstrated above. If you want to use it in a puppet rule after `=>` first assign it to a variable, then use the variable after `=>`.

Comment: Should work fine after a `=>`, Tully. What version of Puppet are you using?

Comment: This is an alternative to concatenation, but not an answer to the question as posed.  If the OP's  need is satisfied, that's useful, but there's many cases where this will not do, at least without intermediary steps.  E.g. if you are trying to avoid assigning a thousand character long string in puppet code with the whole thing on one line, or if one of the things you are concatenating is the output of a function call.

Answer (score 25):

I use the construct where I put the values into an array an then 'join' them.
In this example my input is an array and after those have been joined with the ':2181,' the resulting value is again put into an array that is joined with an empty string as separator.

```
$zookeeperservers = [ 'node1.example.com', 'node2.example.com', 'node3.example.com' ]
$mesosZK = join([ "zk://" , join($zookeeperservers,':2181,') ,":2181/mesos" ],'')
```

resulting value of $mesosZK

```
zk://node1.example.com:2181,node2.example.com:2181,node3.example.com:2181/mesos
```

Comment: This uses the puppetlabs-stdlib module's [join](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib#join) function, for those wondering.

Comment: Or the internal function (https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#join), as of Puppet 5.5.

Answer (score 21):

Another option not mentioned in other answers is using [Puppet's `sprintf()`](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/function.html#sprintf) function, which functions identically to the [Ruby function](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sprintf) behind it. An example:

```
$x = sprintf('hello user %s', 'CoolUser')
```

Verified to work perfectly with puppet. As mentioned by *chutz*, this approach can also help you concatenate the output of functions.

Comment: This way it is possible to concatenate the output of functions - something not so easy with other answers. E.g. `$x = sprintf('%s/%s', dirname($file), $anotherfile)`

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me.

```
puppet apply -e ' $y = "Hello" $z = "world" $x = "$y $z" notify { "$x": } '
notice: Hello world
notice: /Stage[main]//Notify[Hello world]/message: defined 'message' as 'Hello world'
notice: Finished catalog run in 0.04 seconds
```

The following works as well:

```
$abc = "def"

file { "/tmp/$abc":
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work when one of the terms is an expression.  *E.g.*,

`$foo = regsubst($bar, '/', '-', 'G') + $version`

Comment: You can put the output of the expression into another intermediary variable first.  i.e. `$temp=regsubst($bar, '/', '-', 'G')` and then `$foo = "${temp}${version}"`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the join() function from puppetlabs-stdlib.  I was thinking there should be a string concat function there, but I don't see it.  It'd be easy to write one.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [docs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.6/lang_data_string.html#interpolation), you can just use ${varname} interpolation. And that works with function calls as well:

```
$mesosZK = "zk://${join($zookeeperservers,':2181,')}:2181/mesos"
$x = "${dirname($file)}/anotherfile"
```

Could not use {} with function arguments though: got `Syntax error at '}'`.