# Puppet conditional assignment and += operator

Tags: string, variables, scope, puppet

In puppet, I want to write a file with a string based on configuration in `nodes.pp`.

- `nodes.pp` defines the `$sslClientCertConfig` variable, which has a `loadBalancerIp` property.
- I want to create a configuration string, we'll call it `$config`, without repeating the string code. The configuration string should be either

  - A: if `loadBalancerIp` is a valid string, a combination of strings 1 and 2
  - B: if `loadBalancerIp` is an empty string, only string 2
- Then, using that configuration string, I want to set another variable.

I know that puppet only allows a single declaration of a variable name per scope, but I do not know if it supports the `+=` operator, or if the variable declarations below will work for the if/else clause later.

Here's what I want to try:

```
if $sslClientCertConfig {
    $loadBalancerIp = $sslClientCertConfig[loadBalancerIp]

    $config

    if $loadBalancerIp {
          $config += "string1"
    }
    $config += "string2"
}

if $config {
   $custom = "true"
} else {
    $custom = "false"
}
```

Is this pattern supported by puppet? Is there a way I can improve this?

Comment: What is the underlying problem that you are trying to solve? Is this a difference in environments? While [there is a Puppet pattern for string concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14885263/78845), there is likely to be a better way, perhaps using Hiera.

Comment: In your example you do not need any `+=`,  just  use:   `if  loadBalancerIp { $config = "string1" } else { $config = "string2" }`

Comment: Avoid `+=` it likely does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot [reassign](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/variables.html#no-reassignment) variables in puppet. Instead remove *empty* declaration of `$config` and
 try the following code

```
if $loadBalancerIp {
      $prefix = "string1"
}
$config = "${prefix}string2"
```

Example:

```
$prefix1 = "pref1"
$config1 = "${prefix1}blabla1"
$config2 = "${prefix2}blabla2"
notify { $config1: }
notify { $config2: }
```

> Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Notify[pref1blabla1]/message: defined 'message' as 'pref1blabla1'
>   Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Notify[blabla2]/message: defined 'message' as 'blabla2'

**UPDATE:** Be aware of [automatic string to boolean conversion.](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.8/reference/lang_datatypes.html#automatic-conversion-to-boolean)